# Stackoverflow Personal Tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, users

Wouldn't it be cool if each user could have "Personal Tags", tags that the user themselves could see/search, but that wouldn't be shown to the rest of the community?

This way questions could be grouped by the project the individual user is using the question/answers for.

Comment: This is going to get down-voted, so I probably won't bother.

Comment: It has happened before http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17314/search-for-a-tag-returns-no-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *so many* tools to managing personal web content. Find one that suits your specific needs rather than adding unnecessary complexity to individual web sites. I'm talking about web tools such as bookmarks/favorites, [RSS readers](http://reader.google.com), [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com), [Onenote](http://www.onenote.com), etc, etc.

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: Yeah I just remembered I can do the same thing with bookmarking and tagging my questions using del.icio.us